# Nelder-Mead algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, performance, beginner

I am currently learning C# since the last week. I have little to no prior experience with any of the C family of languages.

I implemented the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) for numerical optimisation of a function. My implementation exists of a function that takes two arguments, the function to optimize, and the amount of dimensions that the function has. So for a function that goes R^N -> R, the second argument would be N.

The implementation is based on the algorithm shown in the linked article.

Along with the algorithm, I also implemented two functions for evaluation of the algorithm: The [Himmelblau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmelblau%27s_function) and the [Rosenbrock function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function).

```
using System;

public class NelderMead
{
    public static int num_of_functioncalls = 0;

    public static double HimmelBlau(double[] x)
    {
        num_of_functioncalls++;
        return Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x[0], 2) + x[1] - 11, 2) + Math.Pow(x[0] + Math.Pow(x[1], 2) - 7, 2);
    }

    public static double RosenBrock(double[] x)
    {
        num_of_functioncalls++;
        return Math.Pow(1 - x[0], 2) + 100 * Math.Pow(x[1] - Math.Pow(x[0], 2), 2);
    }


    public static double[] optimizer(Func<double[], double> function, int N)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        double[][] simplex = new double[N + 1][];

        // Generate N + 1 initial arrays.
        for (int array = 0; array <= N; array++)
        {
            simplex[array] = new double[N];
            for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
            {
                simplex[array][index] = rnd.NextDouble() * 20 - 10;
            }
        }
        const double alpha = 1;
        const double gamma = 2;
        const double rho = 0.5;
        const double sigma = 0.5;

        // Infinite loop until convergence
        while (true)
        {
            // Evaluation
            double[] functionValues = new double[N + 1];
            int[] indices = new int[N + 1];
            for (int vertex_of_simplex = 0; vertex_of_simplex <= N; vertex_of_simplex++)
            {
                functionValues[vertex_of_simplex] = function(simplex[vertex_of_simplex]);
                indices[vertex_of_simplex] = vertex_of_simplex;
            }

            // Order
            Array.Sort(functionValues, indices);

            // Check for convergence
            if (functionValues[N] - functionValues[0] < 1e-9)
            {
                break;
            }


            // Find centroid of the simplex excluding the vertex with highest functionvalue.
            double[] centroid = new double[N] ;

            for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
            {
                centroid[index] = 0;
                for (int vertex_of_simplex = 0; vertex_of_simplex <= N; vertex_of_simplex++)
                {
                    if (vertex_of_simplex != indices[N])
                    {
                        centroid[index] += simplex[vertex_of_simplex][index] / N;
                    }
                }
            }



            //Reflection
            double[] reflection_point = new double[N];
            for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
            {
                reflection_point[index] = centroid[index] + alpha * (centroid[index] - simplex[indices[N]][index]);
            }

            double reflection_value = function(reflection_point);

            if (reflection_value >= functionValues[0] & reflection_value < functionValues[N - 1])
            {
                simplex[indices[N]] = reflection_point;
                continue;
            }


            // Expansion
            if (reflection_value < functionValues[0])
            {
                double[] expansion_point = new double[N];
                for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
                {
                    expansion_point[index] = centroid[index] + gamma * (reflection_point[index] - centroid[index]);
                }
                double expansion_value = function(expansion_point);

                if (expansion_value < reflection_value)
                {
                    simplex[indices[N]] = expansion_point;
                }
                else
                {
                    simplex[indices[N]] = reflection_point;
                }
                continue;
            }

            // Contraction
            double[] contraction_point = new double[N];
            for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
            {
                contraction_point[index] = centroid[index] + rho * (simplex[indices[N]][index] - centroid[index]);
            }

            double contraction_value = function(contraction_point);

            if (contraction_value < functionValues[N])
            {
                simplex[indices[N]] = contraction_point;
                continue;
            }

            //Shrink
            double[] best_point = simplex[indices[0]];
            for (int vertex_of_simplex = 0; vertex_of_simplex <= N; vertex_of_simplex++)
            {
                for(int index = 0; index < N; index++)
                {

                    simplex[vertex_of_simplex][index] = best_point[index] + sigma * (simplex[vertex_of_simplex][index] - best_point[index]);

                }
            }

        }

        return simplex[0];
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        double[] result = new double[2];
        result = optimizer(RosenBrock, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("RosenBrock formula:");
        Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0}, {1}", result[0], result[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of functiecalls: {0}", num_of_functioncalls);
        num_of_functioncalls = 0;

        result = optimizer(HimmelBlau, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("HimmelBlau formula:");
        Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0}, {1}", result[0], result[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of functiecalls: {0}", num_of_functioncalls);
        num_of_functioncalls = 0;

    }
}
```

Because I am new to C#, I am interested in advice/commentary on good form, but I am also interested in the efficiency of this implementation.

Comment: What the heck is with the capitalization in the method names `HimmelBlau` and `RosenBrock`? That's not the names of the algorithms nor the people who came up with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With advancing insight I have found a few issues with the code.

## Check for convergence doesn't work properly

```
        // Check for convergence
        if (functionValues[N] - functionValues[0] < 1e-9)
        {
            break;
        }
```

This checks if the minimal and maximal function values of the simplex are sufficiently close together, but an easy counterexample shows that this nowhere near guarantees convergence:

Consider the function `f(x) = x^2`. Of course this is trivial to minimize, but using this algorithm, we would have a simplex of 2 points. Let those points at some point using the algorithm be `1` and `-1`. Then the functionvalues will both be `1`, and the algorithm will stop.

Instead, I changed this to checking the value of the centroid of the simplex.

```
        if (Math.Abs(function(centroid) - functionValues[0]) < 1e-5)
        {
            break;
        }
```

## There is an unnecessary amount of calls to `function`.

Each iteration starts by evaluating all points of the simplex:

```
    for (int vertex_of_simplex = 0; vertex_of_simplex <= N; vertex_of_simplex++)
    {
        functionValues[vertex_of_simplex] = function(simplex[vertex_of_simplex]);
        indices[vertex_of_simplex] = vertex_of_simplex;
    }
```

However, in most cases, only one of the points of the simplex changes between iterations. So only one point needs to be re-evaluated. Conveniently, this re-evaluation is already done in the previous iteration:

```
       double reflection_value = function(reflection_point);
       double expansion_value = function(expansion_point);
       double contraction_value = function(contraction_point);
```

Only during shrinking do we have to evaluate more new points. So we can extend the code where we break the iteration with a modification of the `functionValues` array and move the loop evaluating the simplex to outside the while-loop.

```
        if (reflection_value >= functionValues[0] & reflection_value < functionValues[N - 1])
        {
            simplex[indices[N]] = reflection_point;
            functionValues[N] = reflection_value;

            continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Array.Sort(functionValues, indices);
> ```

I could be missing something, but I don't see a need for this. If you're only using the minimum and maximum then you can find them in linear time rather than the quasilinear time which a sort requires. Although given your observations in your own answer about reusing values between loop iterations perhaps the optimal approach would be a binary heap to track the maximum and a separate variable to track the minimum.

As far as C# style, the variable names should use camel case rather than underscores. And possibly I would use some Linq instead of some of those loops, but unless you're coming from a functional background that doesn't need to be your first priority.

Comment: Hmm, in the usecase I am using this implementation for, I only work with 5 dimensions, so I would be sorting only 6 values. I also use this to find the index of the maximum and minimum, which is sorted alongside in `indices`.

Comment: Actually, I found the reason to sort. There are three values I need to know: the lowest value, the highest value and the second highest value. The last one is needed for the check on whether to accept the reflection point: `if (reflection_value >= functionValues[0] & reflection_value < functionValues[N - 1])`.

Comment: You could still peek at the second-largest value with a binary heap, but I agree that if you're only sorting 5 values then the algorithmic complexity of the sort is pretty much irrelevant.